# Why doesn't my jquery code add rows to html table on fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have written this code to add rows and columns on the fly to my html table but it doesn't. Why?

```
$.each(response.lstTimeSlotsReturned, function (i, slots)
                {                        
                    $("#tbodytblAvailableAppointments").find('tbody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').html('Td')));
                });
```

Full code:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return;
    }

    var url = '@Url.Action("ShowAvailableAppointments")';
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function (response) {

        if (response.ReturnStatusJSON == true) {
            swal("Booked !", "Done", "success");

            $.each(response.lstTimeSlotsReturned, function (i, slots)
            {                        
                $("#tbodytblAvailableAppointments").find('tbody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').html('Td')));
            });                    
        }
        else {
            swal("Sorry !", "Failed", "error");                  
        }
    });
});
```

Update: HTML table

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tblAvailableAppointments" class="table table-condensed">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Timings</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbodytblAvailableAppointments">

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried many other strategies but none worked. It has taken a lot of time.

Comment: You need to provide the HTML code too, there will be probably some wrong selectors in your JS

Comment: Do you really have `<table>` with id `tbodytblAvailableAppointments`? Does it really have `<tbody>`?

Comment: you have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS is trying to select `tbody` under element with id `#tbodytblAvailableAppointments`. But that is id of the `tbody` itself. Just remove the `find('tbody')` part:

```
$("#tbodytblAvailableAppointments").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').html('Td')));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#tbodytblAvailableAppointments").find('tbody')`

`#tbodytblAvailableAppointments` already is `tbody`, so you won't find the tbody you're looking for.